# Why is VScode not compiling LaTex file when pdflscape is used?

Tags: pgfplots, vscode, pdflscape, latex-workshop

I've been trying to compile the following document in VScode using LaTeX workshop but for some reason it doesn't compile. Furthermore, it seems that the pgfplots package is also hindering compilation.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{design_ASC}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{makecell} % for double-line headers on tables
%\usepackage{gensymb}
% TIKZ==============================
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
% ============
\usepackage[mode=build]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
...
```

I get the following error

```
Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.
Latexmk: Missing input file 'pdflscape.sty' (or dependence on it) from following:
  '! LaTeX Error: File `pdflscape.sty' not found.'
Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (437,65001)
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'main.fls'
PWD line not in UTF-8
Latexmk: Examining 'main.log'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'main.log' for details
```

I don't know why it's asking me for a `pdflscape.sty`. The source is LaTeX Workshop.
If I comment out pdflscape, it give's me the following error

```
Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.
Latexmk: Missing input file 'currfile.sty' (or dependence on it) from following:
  '! LaTeX Error: File `currfile.sty' not found.'
Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (437,65001)
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'main.fls'
PWD line not in UTF-8
Latexmk: Examining 'main.log'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'main.log' for details
```

I googled it but couldn't find anything. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: well it is asking you for pdflscape because your document contains \usepackage{pdflscape}. Install the package with the tools of your tex system or OS.

Comment: Similar for `currfile`. You are using package `standalone`. Package `standalone` requires package `currfile`. So you have to install it.